# How to provide 3rd argument to Mapreduce program in addition to input and output location?

Tags: mapreduce

I am at learner level for `Hadoop MapReduce`. Just trying , if I can provide an additional argument for program in JAVA. Basically I am trying to search a keyword in all input files, and want to provide the keyword as an argument, but `Mapper interface` has only single `map()` function, which do allow to add an additional argument.

Any help for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set arguments in your configuration

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("keyword","bob");
//bob can also be passed as an argument
//conf.set("keyword",args[3]); * note that both are string arguments
```

Inside mapper you can get this configuration from context and search for the keyword...

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context){
    String keyword = context.getConfiguration().get("keyword");//does the job for you
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this, from passing parameters using a -D style parameter definition, to using hadoop configuration:

See here: http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2011/11/passing-parameters-to-mappers-and.html